# Sending large Model list from view to controller c# mvc razor

Tags: javascript, c#, json, razor, model

I have got very large model list in view and i would like to send the list back to controller using ajax query. I have tried to send the whole model list back but since the model is too large, it exceeds the json maxlength specified within web.config. The encode method works for smaller list though.

`var jsonString = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.modelName_small));`

Only way that i can vision it to work is but filtering the large model list into smaller list using javascript (similar to a 'Where' SQL statement). My script are as follows (razor):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function functionName(input1_decimal) {

        var smallerList = new Array();

        @foreach (var item in Model.modelName)
        {
            //input1_decimal should be within a certain range
            @:if (input1_decimal - 0.1 <= @item.Property1) && (@item.Property1 <= input1_decimal + 0.1)
            {
                @:smallerList.push("@item");
            }            
        }
        //convert smallerList to json and send it to controller
     }

<script>
```

it seems quite straight forward but I just can not get it to work. Might be something quite trivial. I have also tried:

```
var smallerList= Model.modelName.Where(x => (input1_decimal - 0.1 <= x.Property1) && (x.Property1 <= input1_decimal + 0.1));
```

Similarly, i have also tried

```
        var smallerList = Model.modelName.filter(function (item) {
           return (input1_decimal - 0.1 <= item.Property1) && (item.Property1<= input1_decimal + 0.1)
        });
```

Thank you for your patience. i hope i have explained it clearly as to what i am trying to achieve. I am not a developer. Programming just for fun and self education.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of editing jsonmaxlength field within web.config, I assigned MaxJsonLength  to Int32.MaxValue. Created a list and assigned properties to model properties and serialise into Json object list. Then i filtered the list using $.grep function. Finally, I was able to send objJsonSmallList back to controller... Happy days :)

```
@{
     var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
     js.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
     //Create a list and assigning all the properties of the model
     var data = Model.model_Name.Select(x => new
            {
                propName1 = x.property1,
                propName2 = x.property2,
                ...
                propNameN = x.propertyN
             });
      //serialize collection of anonymous objects
      string strArr = js.Serialize(data);
}

var objJsonBigList = JSON.parse('@strArr'.replace(/&quot;/g, '"'));

//small Filtered list send to controller via Ajax
var objJsonSmallList = $.grep(objJsonBigList, function (n) {
   return ((input1_decimal- 0.1 <= n.Prop) && (n.Prop <= input1_decimal + 0.1))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you modifying data on the view ? If so, one other approach is to post only modified data to the controller in order to minimized the json string length and retrieve the rest of the data directly in the controller.

Comment: Yea modifying the data in the view hence why i am trying to filter the model list to send only a small useful portion of data